# Por que me da NaN?

Tags: javascript, reduce

queria consultar si alguien al ver el codigo puede ayudarme a decir por que me da NaN el reduce().. adjunto codigo
Gracias !!

```
const sortPaddockTypeByTotalArea = () => {
const paddockFarm = paddockType.map((paddock)=> {
  const paddockArea = paddocks.reduce((acumulador, actual) => {
    if (actual.paddockTypeId === paddock.id){
     return  acumulador + actual.paddockArea
    }  return acumulador
  },0);
 return [paddock.name, paddockArea]  

})
```

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si `actual.paddockArea` es `undefined`? Tendrás la suma de un número con `undefined`, lo cual da como resultado `NaN`. Saludos

Comment: Necesitaríamos ver más información para ver lo que está sucediendo, recuerda colocar un ejemplo [mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para poder reproducir tu problema, de lo contrario estaríamos *asumiendo* o *adivinando* cosas, que pueden ser totalmente inciertas, saludos.

Comment: @MauricioContreras con lo que me comentaste pude decifrarlo, asi que muchas gracias !!